# ExactTarget - Approval API

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, approval-process

I am trying to retrieve emails submitted for approval via API.
Did Marketing Cloud implement the Approvals APIs?
If not, when is it estimated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no Approvals Object available in the [SOAP API objects](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/objects/) and the Email Object doesn't contain an approvals property either. Note that the SOAP API is now in maintenance mode and new features won't be added to it.

**However** there are now several Approvals methods available in the [REST API](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/routes.html). You should be able to use the GET Approvals method to retrieve all approvals in the context of the current user. I assume by 'current user' they are referring to the user that you used when you set the permissions while creating your API integration app in [App Center](https://appcenter-auth.s1.marketingcloudapps.com).